# Master Viewer for Change Data Capture

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, audit, change-tracking

Change Data Capture in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition looks great.  It captures all changes which is what we need and it will save us from custom coding this.

A couple other things would go a long way towards an end-to-end solution.  These are:

1) Ability to see all changes across all tables - so maybe not with the data, but something like what type of change was made, to what table, and when.  Is there a management view to get this?  I appreciate that the CDC tables are custom making this less than trivial.

2) Some tool to view the CDC changes stored.  Anyone know of third-party viewers?

-Krip

Answer (score 1):

For item 1, you could use a SProc and Dynamic SQL to generate a result set that contains all tables and changes (by type and time) using the following tables...

[cdc.change_tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522506.aspx)

a database system table that contains a record for each table in the database with CDC enabled.

[cdc.(CAPTURE_INSTANCE)_CD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500305.aspx)

this is the table created to hold the historical changes made to the source table when CDC is first enabled on the source table.  the value for (CAPTURE_INSTANCE) can be found in the capture_instance column of the first table (cdc.change_tables)